# slice[:1][0] vs slice[0] in go

Tags: go, pointers, slice

In the documentation of the [unsafe.SliceData](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#SliceData) function in go, it says:

> `SliceData` returns a pointer to the underlying array of the argument
> slice.
>
> - If `cap(slice)` > 0, `SliceData` returns `&slice[:1][0]`.

What's the logic behind returning `&slice[:1][0]` instead of `&slice[0]`? As far as I'm aware (and my [tests](https://go.dev/play/p/sL2exT3lQZi) confirm), both would return the same address. Is there a specific reason that go developers chose to use the former rather than the latter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slice may have a positive capacity (`cap(slice) > 0`), but it may have `0` length at the same time. Indexing it like `slice[0]` would result in a runtime panic.

If a slice has positive capacity, you may slice it like `slice[:1]` which will result in a slice that will have a length of `1`, and you may index the result like `result[0]` without resulting in a runtime panic.

For example:

```
slice := make([]int, 0, 5)
fmt.Println(&slice[0])
```

This results in:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

But this works:

```
fmt.Println(&slice[:1][0])
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understand: when you access slice with zero length and capacity > 0 as `slice[:1]`, it will return a new slice with a length of 1 (with a value of zero)? But the underlying address of both the original (zero length) slice and the new (`result[:1][0]`) will be the same?

Comment: @aviro A slice is a descriptor of a contiguous part of a backing array. Slicing a slice returns a new descirptor that shares the backing array. The length tells which part you can index. Having length=0 disables accessing the elements. But you can reslice it with a bigger length (up to the capacity), which will give you access to the elements (indexing will become valid). Read blog posts: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro and https://go.dev/blog/slices